# Prolog: Why did the output displayed the same number of output based on the number of kids they have

Tags: prolog

I have the facts and rule as below:

```
/* fact */
parent(parent1, child1).
parent(parent2, child1).
parent(parent1, child2).
parent(parent2, child2).
parent(parent1, child3).
parent(parent2, child3).
parent(parent1, child4).
parent(parent2, child4).

/* rule */
spouse(X, Y):- parent(X, Z), parent(Y, Z), X \= Y.
```

But as I try to execute:

```
spouse(X, parent1).
```

these are the outputs:

```
X = parent2;
X = parent2;
X = parent2;
X = parent2;
false.
```

Seems like the number of the same outputs are based on the number of kids they have. The output should be the only parent2. May I know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Prolog to "collect them all into a set" with [`setof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) and output the set instead, naturally eliminating duplicates:

```
parent(parent1, child1).
parent(parent2, child1).
parent(parent1, child2).
parent(parent2, child2).
parent(parent1, child3).
parent(parent2, child3).
parent(parent1, child4).
parent(parent2, child4).

spouse(X, Y):-
   parent(X, Z), 
   parent(Y, Z),
   X \= Y.
   
spouse_unique(X, Y) :-
   setof([Xso, Yso], spouse(Xso, Yso), Set),
   format("Collected the set ~q~n",[Set]),
   member([X, Y],Set).
```

Here, the `member/2` call picks the elements out of `Set` on redo.

```
?- spouse_unique(X,Y).
Collected the set [[parent1,parent2],[parent2,parent1]]
X = parent1,
Y = parent2 ;
X = parent2,
Y = parent1.
```

```
?- spouse_unique(X,parent1).
Collected the set [[parent1,parent2],[parent2,parent1]]
X = parent2.
```

Comment: So that's mean my existing output is not wrong, just that we need to tune the way it's going to display the output. Am I right?

Comment: @Hingusan In a sense. There are 4 ways of building a successful proof the query `spouse(X, parent1).`, and all of them result in the answer `X = parent2`, which is not really of interest to us, the user. So we just embrace the fact of multiple identical answers and collect all answer into a set, eliminating the uninteresting duplicates. Note that if you somehow already know that will only be interested in the first proof found, you can wrap the query into `once/1`: `once(spouse(X, parent1)).`

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog, no program changes are required. You just need to use the meta-predicate [`distinct/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=distinct/1):

```
?- distinct(spouse(X,parent1)).
X = parent2 ;
false.

?- distinct(spouse(X,Y)).
X = parent1,
Y = parent2 ;
X = parent2,
Y = parent1 ;
false.
```